# Send values from a view with a post and getting them in another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm starting with ASP.net MVC, and I have two views.
The first one is ViewPost, with a  form, which I want that when pressed the input button, will send the info from the form to another view. My code is like this:

```
<h2>ViewPost</h2>
<form method="POST" action="~/Home/NewView">
    Number<input id="id_number"type="text" name="name_number" />
    Text<input id="id_text" type="text" name="name_text" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

In the controller I have this code:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewPost(int? name_number, string name_text)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Also in the controller I have a GET method for the NewView, which will check the values and concat them, and show the resultant String in a ViewBag.Message:

```
        public ActionResult NewView(int? number, String name)
        {
           String urlParam = "";
            if (number.HasValue)
            {
                urlParam += " Value number=" + number;
            }
            if (name != null)
            {
                urlParam += " Value name=" + name;
            }
            if (urlParam == "")
            {
                urlParam = "No values";
            }
            ViewBag.Message = urlParam;

            return View();
        }
```

when I press the submit button, I get 
`Resource not found. Requested URL: /Home/NewView`
but when going by writing the URL I can go with no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is sending a `POST` request:

```
method="POST"
```

But you claim to be expecting a `GET` request:

> in the controller I have a GET method for the NewView

Either change the form to a `GET` request:

```
method="GET"
```

**or** change the controller action to accept a `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewView(int? number, String name)
{
    //...
}
```

---

Additionally, the form element names must be the same as the variables you want them to populate.  So either change them in the form:

```
name="number"
...
name="name"
```

**or** change them in the action method:

```
public ActionResult NewView(int? name_number, String name_text)
```

---

A note on terminology which may clear some of this up for you...

> which I want that when pressed the input button, will send the info from the form to another view

This is incorrect.  You don't send values to a *view*, you send them to a *controller action*.  Anything that goes to the server is generally going to a controller action.  That action method can do whatever it needs to do with those values, including returning a view.

But the overall interaction is that the in-browser code (a link, a form, JavaScript and AJAX, etc.) makes requests to server-side actions and those actions return a variety of responses.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand at all how did it work, and I thought that the controller managed the send and the retrieve. You helped me a lot